# Weston : Customize composition to duplicate window display

Tags: wayland

I want to be able to duplicate a window at the compositor/window manager level.

That is, when the user open a `weston-terminal`, I want to display it as 2 windows, and be able to apply movement/rotation to those windows.

To emphasize, I don't want to have 2 `weston-terminal` open, I really need to duplicate the window's content on screen.

Is that possible with weston and where should I look in the code?

I already compiled it and learned to rotate/move windows using `weston-shell.c` but don't know where to look after.

Comment: It seems that you need to rewrite the rendering engine, which specified by core.backend in weston.ini.

Comment: So my implementation would have to be backend-dependant?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is yes. i.e. you need to customize the backend to show window as 2 duplicated. e.g. If you use x11 as the backend of weston, you should look into the _weston/src/compositor-x11.c_ to find how to show the drawn surface provided by client.

Comment: Is that is possible to fetch a wl_surfaces ? I was thinking about creating an empty surface, and fetch a wl_buffer from an existing surface, then use it in the empty surface.

Comment: @gzh I succeed in it and it´s not backend dependent.

Comment: @ErwanDouaille, I have seen your pretty cool video, would you like share some hint about what you hacked on weston?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the Weston implementation, in the manner you've described. You'd have to hack your own Weston implementation to do this, such that one client can bind to multiple surfaces.

An alternative to consider is to have a surface and subsurface, and have you client render to both the main surface and the subsurface.